# How to use Temp file generated using GetTempFileName() as command line input for createProcess()

Tags: c++, c, windows

The case I need to handle is:

1, I need to generate a temp file (the path and name is created using GetTempFileName().
2, Using this temp file as command line for createProcess ().

Code looks like below:

```
char * tempFile = GenerateTmpFile ();   // self defined function (call GetTempFileName() to get temp file, return temp file path + name ,  so tempFile looks like c:\temp\x.tmp

char szCmd[1024];
strcpy(szCmd, "child.exe ");
strcat(szCmd, tempFile);   // so example of szCmd is: child.exe c:\temp\x.tmp

CreateProcess(NULL,
              szCmd,
              ...
              );
```

But CreateProcess always fails, return error code 2 (2 is from GetLastError(), CreateProcess returns 0), I am thinking the problem is because of the temp file path, if I give

```
szCmd ="child.exe c:\\temp\\x.tmp"
```

manually, it works fine.

Does anyone know how I could get CreateProcess working with the temp file path+name generated from getTempFileName()?

Update: 
I tried to add '\' to make '\' in the path to be double backslash, so the path for example is:

```
c:\\temp\\x.tmp
```

It still does not work.

Why is it different from calling CreateProcess with a string literal?

```
 CreateProcess(NULL,
               "child.exe c:\\temp\\x.tmp",
               ...);
```

Comment: If your temp file path contains embedded spaces, you will need to add quotes around that string.

Comment: Are you returning a valid dynamically allocated string from GenerateTmpFile?

Comment: Yes, I think it is valid, it is something looks like: c:\Users\username\appdata...., I checked the location and got the file there. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: no embedded space is contained in the path and the name, it is : c:\Users\Username\appdata\local\temp\x.tmp

Comment: Try CreateProcessA(...);

Comment: Output the szCmd string (via printf or MessageBox as appropriate) and compare it to what it ought to be.  If in doubt, post it here.

Comment: Did you really just change the call to CreateProcess (giving the string literal) or also not call `GenerateTmpFile`? Does `GenerateTmpFile` change the current directory?

Comment: Double backslash is only needed in string literals (which the compiler parses). You do not need the double backslashes in the szCmd string!